# Import less file using file-loader in webpack

Tags: webpack, webpack-file-loader

I want to use file-loader to generate versioned less file import

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="/static/styles.<VERSION/HASH>.less" />
```

I expect that I can then just

```
import '@/assets/styles.less'
```

in `main.js`.

I need this only for versioning (auto rename file each time when I modify my `styles.less` file), I don't want to compile less during compiletime, because I am using `less.modifyVars` in runtime. So I am using

```
import '@/assets/less.min.js'
```

which searches for `rel="stylesheet/less"` tags and compiles it.
When I add manually in index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="/static/styles.less" />
```

all works, but I need versioning for continuous delivery

What I tried is add next rule to loaders:

```
{
    test: /\.less$/,
    loader: 'file-loader',
},
```

But during compile I get:

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                           13:05:04

This dependency was not found:

* @/assets/styles.less in ./src/main.js

To install it, you can run: npm install --save @/assets/styles.less
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration bellow works like you want. You can find this example on [github](https://github.com/Deathangel908/less-fileloader).

**src/main.js**:

```es6
import a from "@/assets/styles.less"

console.log(`You don't need to import less file here at all, only in index.ejs but if you need the reference, there you have it: ${a}`);
```

**assets/styles.less**

```less
  // Variables
@link-color:        #428bca; // sea blue
@link-color-hover:  darken(@link-color, 10%);

// Usage
a,
.link {
  color: @link-color;
}
a:hover {
  color: @link-color-hover;
}
.widget {
  color: #fa0;
  background: @link-color;
}
```

**webpack.config.js**:

```js
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const path = require('path')
module.exports = {
  entry: ['./src/main.js'],
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({template: 'src/index.ejs'}),
  ],
  devtool: '#source-map',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.less', '.js'], // not require
    alias: {'@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')}
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          publicPath: '', // you can override this to put less output in different folder
          name: 'static/[name].[ext]?[sha512:hash:base64:6]' // I guess you want the filename to stay the same after it's modified
        }
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

**src/index.ejs**:

```ejs
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="<%= require('@/assets/styles.less') %>" />
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Please note that the exception bellow tells you that it can't find file `@/assets/styles.less`. Please make sure you specified the correct path, and if you use aliases instead of relative path, you have the correct alias in `webpack.config.js`.

> ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors
>   13:05:04
>
> This dependency was not found:
>
> - @/assets/styles.less in ./src/main.js
>
> To install it, you can run: npm install --save @/assets/styles.less